# Texture painting wired issue

Tags: texture-painting

There is a wired boundary around the big hole, everywhere else is fine, the small hole does not have this problem. Does anyone know what causes this problem? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe recalculate the normals?

Comment: normals are facing the right direction.

Comment: maybe share your file?

Comment: Can you check and share what the subdivision modifier is set to?

Comment: I have trouble uploading the file here. The subdivision is 3. The normals are right. There are detailed images uploaded to the original post. Thanks, everyone.